# Where can I find a comprehensive guide for starting to understand and use SPF records?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, spf

I haven't done much with SPF records before. I understand that the concept behind them is to specify which servers (ip's) are allowed to send mail signed "from" a particular domain - which is increasingly important as it seems e-mail services are tightening up security lately.

I see there are a lot of questions on serverfault related to SPF, and there are a lot of web pages out there that I've found via Google, but most pages are very specific to a particular web host.

So, my question is, what resources would you recommend reading up on before posting SPF record questions here? I'm hoping for a comprehensive guide, both for understanding and implementing SPF records, but one that someone without much SPF background could get a lot out of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try http://www.openspf.org?  Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework ?

Comment: There's even an RFC on it for those with chronic insomnia! (RFC 4408 -> http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4408 )

Comment: Thanks. Those look good. I'm not usually too fond of wikipedia for technical stuff because it doesn't usually tell you "how to implement" things, but it looks ok for this.

Comment: @cwd, Wikipedia is a great resource, just don't stop reading after the first paragraph.  Usually if you look down at the References, and External links sections you will find links to the official documentation, specifications, and so on.

Comment: You can also use Microsoft's wizard to create SPF records: http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [openspf documentation](http://www.openspf.org/).  I find it is quite clear.

I posted on [Securing your Email Reputation with SPF](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/securing-your-email-reputation-with-spf/).

---